# AngularJS ng-show not working properly

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and already getting frustrated why a simple ng-show isn't working as expected.

I want to show/hide a div depending on the state of a flag (flightsProcessed)

```
fp: {{flightsProcessed}}
<div class="container-fluid" ng-show="flightsProcessed">
        aaa
    </div>
```

I have a controller which at the beginning has something like :

```
$scope.flightsProcessed = false;
```

Afterwards, in another function which is triggered upon $http.success() I do something like:

```
$scope.flightsProcessed = true;
```

My question is why isn't the div shown when flightsProcessed = true although when I print it above it, flightsProcessed = true?

I've tried to use the $apply but I get <`$digest already in progress`>

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mattbodman/8Zbxq/2/ which uses $http to simulate what you're trying to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the view is not updating, it's usually because the scope variable you think you're modifying (flightsProcessed) is not the actual scope variable that you're expecting.  This might happen if you're inside a directive that creates a child scope (like ng-repeat, ng-include, ng-view, etc) and then you assign flightsProcessed with a value which inadvertently creates a new scope variable in the child scope. This breaks model binding so that updates to the view are no longer propagated.

To see if this is happening, try:

```
  $scope.$parent.flightsProcessessed = true;
```

To see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Hi - I got stuck on same thing , i want to learn more about this things to get the idea of what was actually happening ,

Answer (score 3):

Your view is taking a copy of the value.  So when it changes later, it is not seeing that change.  Try creating a scope function that returns the value, call it `getFlightsProcessed` or something along those lines.  Then just change your `ng-show` to point to your scope function `getFlightsProcessed()`

It is easy to get frustrated when learning something new.  However, stick with it because Angular is worth the learning curve.

Comment: I agree AngularJS is worth the learning curve, but are you sure about the rest of your answer?  I set existing $scope values all the time in success functions and it works fine, but maybe I've just been lucky.  Could you expand on your statement "your view is taking a copy of the value"?

Comment: I was way off on this one.  For some reason I had thought this was what was happening and even then what I said was incorrect!  Thanks for pointing it out.  http://stsc3000.github.io/blog/2013/10/26/a-tale-of-frankenstein-and-binding-to-service-values-in-angular-dot-js/

Comment: Your first sentence was very helpful to me. I was using ng-show="{{variableName}}" instead of ng-show="variableName" which means it *was* taking a copy of the value. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1 - Angular team programmer suggest that , **Always use a DOT**! . that means , when you want to define a $scope.something  , its better that **something** always be an object .(you want to know why , search:()

2- scope.$apply isnt just what you think , that when ever my scope manupulation didn't work , I will use a scope.$apply to fix it , **NOPE**  , there is a great strategy behind the scope.$apply .

When ever you want to manupulate scope from outsite of the angular world , your must fire a scope.$apply . E.g: when you want to manupulate a scope.something in a **directive**.

And for your question . you must do like this :

in your controller :

```
           $scope.flights = {};
           $scope.flights.flightsProcessed = false;// Notice that how I used a DOT
```

Then you can do what you wanted to do ;

Answer (score 1):

Show more of your code? You've got the right idea. Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpjaD/19/). It basically shows what you're trying to do.

Html..

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
      <div ng-show="flightsProcessed">Aaaaa</div>
      <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" ng-click="invert()"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Angular...

```
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.flightsProcessed = true;
    $scope.invert = function() {
        $scope.flightsProcessed = !$scope.flightsProcessed;
    };
}
```